# Processing exclusive command line switches using Python optparse

Tags: python, optparse

I need to accept one of three switches on the command line, `--major`, `--minor` or `--patch` or none of them in which the default is minor. I'm doing this using `optparse` due to the limitations of the environment (Python 2.6.x) so I can't change that.

What I'd ideally like to achieve is that `optparse` does the heavy lifting so I don't have to write code to check that the options are exclusive etc. I'd also appreciate if it can give a neat and understandable output from `--help` such as, for example:

```
[--major|minor|patch]   whether to build as a new major/minor/patch
                        version. minor is default.
```

Or something similar (i.e. ideally all on the same line). I tried the following:

```
parser.add_option('', '--major', dest='rel_type')
parser.add_option('', '--minor', dest='rel_type')
parser.add_option('', '--patch', dest='rel_type')
```

but for `--help` that gave me:

```
--major=REL_TYPE
--minor=REL_TYPE
--patch=REL_TYPE
```

I know it's possible to use:

```
... type='choice', choices=['major', 'minor', 'patch'] ...
```

but this isn't really what I want as these are *value* enumerations rather than *switch* options.

Is this possible, and if so how?